# How to add runat server to cls file

Tags: html, asp.net, runat

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    html += "<tr class=\"GreyBorder\" id='tblFilesGrid_" + dr["Id"].ToString() + "' 
                pkid=\"" + dr["id"].ToString() + "\"  class=\"DataRow\">";
                html += "<td class=\"GreyBorder\" style=\"text-align:center !important;\">" + Count + 
                "</td>";

    html += "<td  align=\"center\" >" + dr["Name"] + "</td> ";

    html += "<td class=\"GreyBorder\" align='center'><img id='view' title='view' 
                onclick=showDocument('" + dr["id"] + "');  src='../../Images/folder.gif'> &nbsp&nbsp 
                <img title='remove' onclick='return DeleteRow(this)'  src='../../images/delete.png'> 
                </td>";

    html += "</tr>";
    Count++;
}
```

This is my dynamic grid which has an onclick function showDocument. I need to code this function in my code behind. For this I  have added runat server attribute in my div tag in aspx page. How would I modify this line of code now to access my function in code behind??

```
html += "<td class=\"GreyBorder\" align='center'><img id='view' title='view' 
            onclick=showDocument('" + dr["id"] + "');  src='../../Images/folder.gif'> &nbsp&nbsp 
            <img title='remove' onclick='return DeleteRow(this)'  src='../../images/delete.png'> 
            </td>";
```

I added runat server attribute in my aspx but after adding runat server, my grid is not showing.

```
 <div id="divFilesGrid"  runat="server" > </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing apples and oranges. what you wrote is dynamic html ("on the fly") runat="server" is for well defined Microsoft server side components (like `<asp:Label>` or `<asp:DropDownList>` or whatever). These two don't mix.

Comment: Just like when I write this <input type="button" ID="btnUpload" runat="server" value="Upload" onserverclick="Upload" />  I can access my id in code behind. In the same way I want to access my function showDocument in code behind. how can I do so?

Comment: I was told to add runat server attribute in my grid above

Comment: Ok, then please ask the one who told you. BTW, if you do find a hack to mix "high level server side components" with "low level html rendered html" please share with us, as I for one would really like to learn that trick.

Comment: I added runat server attribute to my div tag in aspx. This way can i access my function in code behind?

Comment: what would i have to change in my grid above? just change onclick to onserverclick?

Comment: @LongChalk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248437/asp-net-parsing-raw-html-into-controls